# The connection sends response code 405 even when the the url has get method that is used here

Tags: android

I have used a url to connect that should return 200 or something as response code.But i am getting 405 which means that the type of method used is incorrect. But the postman url has get method for response.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new SendRequest().execute();
}

public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
         String authtoken="";
        try{

            URL url = new URL("http://direct-me.herokuapp.com/core/docks/");



            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", authtoken);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();

            /*OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();*/

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added internet permissions ?

Comment: @Yoleth yes i have added the permissions

Comment: I think  have solved it myself. The problem was with the setDoOutput and setDoInput method. They were forcing the application to send post request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think have solved it myself. The problem was with the setDoOutput and setDoInput method. They were forcing the application to send post request